# Using a Gradle extension object in tasks for name lookup

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Suppose I have a Gradle plugin where I do this:

```kotlin
class MyPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        val extension = project.extensions.create<MyExtension>("myExtension")
    }
}
```

The extension looks like this:

```kotlin
interface MyExtension {
    val entries: NamedObjectDomainContainer<MyType>
}
```

Now, suppose I have a task:

```kotlin
abstract class MyTask : DefaultTask() {
    @get:Input
    abstract val entryName: Property<String>
    
    @get:Internal
    abstract val entries: NamedDomainObjectCollection<MyType>
    
    // Presume the rest of the task does something with this
    @get:Nested
    abstract val entry: Property<MyType>
    
    init {
        // ie. by default, entry is populated by looking up the entryName from entries
        entry.convention(entryName.flatMap { entries.named(it) })
    }
}
```

If I were to add code that looks like this in `MyPlugin`:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<MyEntry>().configureEach {
    // Do something with entries here
}
```

How should I populate `entries` from `extension.entries`? Also, would adding, say, a rule, preserve compatibility with Gradle Configuration Cache, or would accessing any part of `extension` be "off-limits"?